# PHP script can't read CLI arguments when extra extensions are enabled in php.ini

Tags: configuration, php

I hope that I'm posting in the right StackExchange.

I am facing a very strange problem with PHP CLI.
I'm using Symfony Framework and I can't use Symfony's commands properly when I add extensions in `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`.

Better than a long speech, watch this:

---

### 1/ Normal output, no extensions

#### `app/console doctrine:schema:update`

```
Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.
```

**→ Ok** *Note: app/console is a PHP script with a shellbang*

#### `app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

```
Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.
```

**→ Ok** (`--force` is a Symfony option, it is passed to the script by PHP)

---

### 2/ Adding two extensions to PHP

I edit php.ini, `sudo vim /etc/php5/cli/php.ini`.
I add two lines:

```
extension=cairo.so
extension=php_gtk2.so
```

These extensions are working perfectly. No warnings, no errors.

---

### 3/ PHP "crash", just added two unrelated extensions

#### `app/console doctrine:schema:update`

```
Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.
```

**→ Ok**...
But:

#### `app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

```
PHP Fatal error:  Option inconnue --force in Unknown on line 0
Could not startup.
```

**→ What?** Not a bug from Symfony...
*Note : `Option inconnue` just means a thing like `Unknown option` in french.*

Same effect on other commands, Symfony commands, or standalone PHP scripts.

---

**Conclusion:** PHP has now a strange way to pass options to the called PHP script.

I also put `php` in front of `app/console` but it does not change anything.
If I comment or remove the extensions in php.ini, everything works. Just these two lines are involved.

Edit : just upgraded PHP from 5.5.12 to 5.6.3, same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am running PHP 5.6.1 (cli) on Linux and had exactly the same problem when I tried to use drush. Every time I run a PHP cli script I recieved:

PHP Fatal error:  Unknown option --whatever-option-you-have

To be sure I created a simple script myself:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
echo ("Test");
```

The error was done away when I deleted "php_gtk2.so" from php.ini.

Does this happen ONLY with php_gtk2.so or whatever extension you put? If you leave only cairo.so, do you get the same error?

This is really strange behavior of PHP!